# "hdf5.h" not found when installing Neon

Tags: python

I'm trying to install Neon, a machine learning package (http://neon.nervanasys.com/docs/latest/installation.html), after cloning the Github repository, cd'ing to the `neon` directory, and running the `make` command I am running into the following error:

```
      ^
    In file included from /tmp/pip-build-2yDIC3/h5py/h5py/defs.c:279:0:
    /tmp/pip-build-2yDIC3/h5py/h5py/api_compat.h:27:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/kurt/Documents/Python/neon/.venv2/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-2yDIC3/h5py/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ArslBc-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/kurt/Documents/Python/neon/.venv2/include/site/python2.7/h5py" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2yDIC3/h5py/
Makefile:115: recipe for target '.venv2/bin/activate' failed
make: *** [.venv2/bin/activate] Error 1
```

The error seems to be associated with h5py, which is a requirement. However, that appears to have been installed correctly:

```
kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~$ sudo pip install h5py
The directory '/home/kurt/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/kurt/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): h5py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.6.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from h5py)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from h5py)
```

I've also tried setting hard links to the "serial" postfixes of the lib names of hdf5, as described in https://github.com/NVIDIA/DIGITS/issues/156, but to no avail. Curiously, if I run the `make` command again, I don't get the same error message but the following:

```
 kurt@kurt-ThinkPad:~/Documents/Python/neon$ make
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kurt/Documents/Python/neon/loader'
Building bin/loader.so...
g++ -shared -o bin/loader.so -fPIC -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -O3 -std=c++11  -DHAS_IMGLIB -DHAS_VIDLIB -DHAS_AUDLIB src/loader.cpp -I/usr/include/opencv   -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lavutil -lavformat -lavcodec -lswscale
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kurt/Documents/Python/neon/loader'
```

It says "Leaving directory" without an explicit error message, but when I try to import `neon` modules I get `ImportError: No module named neon...` errors.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you installed the development package for HDF 5?

Comment: When you ran the first `make` command, were you in a virtualenv? I ask because I see things like `.venv2/bin/activate`.

Comment: Evert, indeed that might be the issue. As I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, according to the instructions I need to install `libdhf5-dev`. When I run `sudo pip install libhdf5-dev` I get an error message: `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libhdf5-dev (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libhdf5-dev`. Perhaps I'll need to ask about this in a separate post.

Answer (score 0):

Following Evert's suggestion (and reading the instructions more carefully), I installed `libhdf5-dev` from a .deb file from http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/libhdf5-dev/download. After this `neon` worked. (It has to be run from a virtual environment).

Comment: Why did you need to install from a `.deb` file? Wouldn't `sudo apt install libhdf5-dev` do it?